# Can Liquibase ignore checksums for a single changeset?

Tags: liquibase, checksum

I’m using Liquibase via the Gradle-Liquibase (v 1.1.1) plugin.  I have the following changeset …

```
<changeSet id="create_my_stored_proc" author="davea" dbms="mysql" runAlways="true">
    <sqlFile endDelimiter="//" path="src/main/resources/scripts/create_my_stored_proc.sql" stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

Is it possible to set something such that checksums are ignored for this changeset only?  The underlying procedure is in a state of flux that could be repeatedly updated and rather than create a new changeset each time, I would like the existing one to run upon every Liquibase build.

Comment: If you have runAlways="true" attribute for changeset it is applied for each Liquibase run is it what you want to achieve?

Comment: What I want is for this to be run every time and for checksums to be ignored.  Does that make sense?

Comment: runAlways="true" runs it every time and checksum is not checked. I see that you already added it so asked for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the `runAlways` and/or `runOnChange` attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the checks per changeSet using the `<validCheckSum>` tag with known good values.

For example, if the previous changeset had a checksum like `8:b3d6a29ce3a75940858cd093501151d1` and you wanted to tweak that changeSet (but not re-apply it where this step has already succeeded) then you could use something like this:

```
<changeSet author="me" id="mychangeset">
  <validCheckSum>8:b3d6a29ce3a75940858cd093501151d1</validCheckSum>
  <sqlFile ... />
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 3):

"RunAlways will still throw a checksum error by default, but you can always use runOnChange=true or any to change that."

Have a look at this ticket raised in liquibase: https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-2506

So, you could do:

```
<changeSet id="create_my_stored_proc" author="davea" dbms="mysql" runAlways="true">
    <validCheckSum>any</validCheckSum>
    <sqlFile endDelimiter="//" path="src/main/resources/scripts/create_my_stored_proc.sql" stripComments="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

Answer (score 2):

Today `validCheckSum` is available in XML/SQL/YAML. You might set a hash, reported by `validate` command or use universal magical hash `1:any` to skip hash check for the changeset.

- [Modify SQL changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547003/modify-sql-changeset)
- [How do I specify validchecksum to any in liquibase formatted sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303898/how-do-i-specify-validchecksum-to-any-in-liquibase-formatted-sql)
- [Adding changes to the old changelog files. Liquibase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75005007/adding-changes-to-the-old-changelog-files-liquibase)