# Modify SQL changeset

Tags: liquibase, rollback, changeset

Liquibase provides a `<validCheckSum>` tag to allow for a new checksum to be specified in case we want to [modify an existing changeset](http://www.liquibase.org/2008/10/dealing-with-changing-changesets.html).

However, this tag is not a valid attribute for [SQL-formatted changesets](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/sql_format.html). There is `runOnChange`, but that's different.

Is there any way of achieving that?

Basically, I made a mistake on a changeset, and I can't even add a rollback command because liquibase detects the checksum change and spits an error, so I'm stuck.

**EDIT**

The concrete changeset that I'm trying to change is:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset myname:0
ALTER TABLE `customers`
CHANGE COLUMN `name` `firstName` VARCHAR(45) NULL;

--changeset myname:1
ALTER TABLE `customers`
ADD COLUMN `lastName` VARCHAR(45) NULL AFTER `firstName`;
```

And I keep it in a file `changelog_1.05.sql`. Finally, I include that file in my `changelog.xml`:

```
<include file="changelog_1.05.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
```

I can't add `<validCheckSum>` because is a SQL-formatted file, so no xml tags can be added there.

Answer (score 3):

Even though it is not documented, looking at the source it appears that validCheckSum is a valid attribute in a formatted sql changelog. You can see [line 105 in FormattedSqlChangelogParser.java](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java#L105) has code to look for this attribute.

Comment: Wow, nice. Unfortunately, it was added less than a month ago and hasn't been released yet.

Comment: I think Liquibase version 3.5.0 is planned to be released by the end of April 2016.

Comment: Good to hear. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I ended up here trying to use the validCheckSum with SQL files in Liquibase 3.9.0.
It works, but only when the "--validCheckSum" is in a new line without other attributes (as opposed to other attributes such as "--runAlways":
    --changeset me:test --runAlways:true --splitStatements:false
    --validCheckSum: 1:any

This seems to be due to the regex for parsing the attribute:
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/17fcfe4f8dae96ddb4caa6793051e47ce64ad933/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/parser/core/formattedsql/FormattedSqlChangeLogParser.java#L87

Answer (score 0):

For SQL grammar use syntax:

```
--validCheckSum VER:HASH
```

It is defined by pattern:

```
private static final String VALID_CHECK_SUM_REGEX = "\\-\\-[\\s]*validCheckSum:? (.*)";
```

You can find `HASH` by running:

```
gradle validate
...
Validation Error:
     1 change sets have changed since they were ran against the database
          liquibase/007-extra.sql::4::admin was: 8:c34ff9f5715de7a8fd548c608c0dfecb but is now: 8:1c13c7c5aec287a3eb1b32093d0b1f1c
```

Hash `1:any` is magical: means ignore the check for the block ))

- [How do I specify validchecksum to any in liquibase formatted sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66303898/how-do-i-specify-validchecksum-to-any-in-liquibase-formatted-sql)