# Adding changes to the old changelog files. Liquibase

Tags: java, database, database-migration, liquibase

I have a lot of changelog files with the initial data for my database. Before all the tables were located in Postgres public schema, but now I have distributed them between different schemas, so that changes with initial data can't reach the tables.

Can I just change all the old files with initial data and add there schemaName="my_schema" or there is another way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once a changeset has been executed, it cannot be modified (assuming runOnChange is not used).  If you modify an already executed changeset you will get a checksum error preventing further deployments.

The best option is to create new changesets that contain the updated sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

You could mark a changeset as valid with the updated checksum. It won't be applied if already applied but will stop to complain about checksum mismatch ))

There is even magical hash to ignore any edits: `1:any` ))

- [Modify SQL changeset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36547003/modify-sql-changeset)